# Cassandra schema for doing hourly queries

Tags: cassandra

I want to store data in Cassandra from many sources and run a job once an hour to process just the data points from a specific hour.  What is the best schema to use for this?

To avoid having a hot spot, I cannot put all the data for an hour in a single partition, so the data for each hour will need to be spread across many partitions.

So I see two ways to allow queries by hour:

1. Create a new table for each hour and do a select * of the table with no where clause to read that hour.  I think this would be efficient for reads and writes, but it would be annoying to have to manage so many tables.
2. Create a new table each week and have a column for the hour number within a week (i.e. 1 to 168), and create a secondary index on it.  Then I can do a select * where hour=x. This appears to work, but I'm worried it won't scale well if there are a lot of rows.

Does anyone know which approach would scale better?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations like that you can use "buckets". A bucket is a way of splitting partitions into several separate pieces. For example, imagine that your schema is as follows:

`CREATE KEYSPACE timeseries WITH replication = {
  'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1
};
USE timeseries;
CREATE TABLE hourly (
  source_id text,
  hour text,
  date timestamp,
  data text,
  bucket int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((hour, bucket), date)
);`

Then you could use `bucket` to divide hours into for example 10 partitions using a hash function of some known identifier (e.g. `source_id`).

At query time, you would need to specify the `hour` and usually all buckets:

`SELECT * FROM hourly WHERE hour = '2015-07-20 23:00' AND bucket IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);`

The hash function is important because you want it to distribute evenly the data amongst the different partitions even if the identified being hashed is not uniformly distributed but also you don't want it to be a very complex function.

This JSFiddle gives you an example hashing function which is very simple, uniformly distributes data and can be easily reproduced in any language: http://jsfiddle.net/joscas/yfp72fq5/

Otherwise instead of a hash function, a modulo of your id or even a modulo of the epoch time could suffice instead of a hash function but if you use a modulo of an id you have to check that the numbers don't end in a uniform pattern. On the other hand, if you take a modulo of a timestamp, you will be effectively writing everything to one bucket for some amount of time and this could be creating hot spots specially if the number of buckets is small.

Comment: Specifying all buckets will cause Cassandra to contact many (possibly all -- depending on cluster size) nodes during read operations. This is a limitation in scalability.

Comment: You can't distribute data to avoid hotspots and at the same time avoid contacting the nodes that have the data. In any case, you control how many nodes (10 in the example). Also I use this in production for very large datasets without problems.

Comment: Sure it's like you say -- the problem is that at query time you won't know which among the 10 partitions contains data so you will contact all nodes when you should contact only one. I am not saying this is not working just that does not exists a clean and working solution.

Comment: @joscas If I hash to N buckets, it seems I could use N clients to process slices of the hourly data in parallel, which would give a nice performance boost.  If I ran a client on each C* node, would there be a way to exploit data locality so that each client would read the data local to the node it was running on? (i.e. the way the spark connector does, but without using spark)

Comment: @JimMeyer yes, you could do that with some effort. In any case I think the DataStax C* driver gives you a lot of options to scale the reading load. A would place to start would be to use the DataStax java driver together with ```TokenAwarePolicy``` http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have many choices and, as you already find out, solutions have drawbacks.

I'd surely avoid solution number 2 due to scalability issue related to secondary indexes. If you need a solution right now I'd use many tables. If you can wait I'd use Cassandra 3 and [materialized views](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) choosing an appropriate key.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Hi Carlo, what key would I use in the materialized view?  If I used the date and hour as a partition key it seems like I'd be back to having a hot spot in the materialized view.  As I understand it, the materialized view is updated with each insert in the base table rather than lazily evaluated.